# Simple Spring mvc project not working, resource not available

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

[image]When put URL = http://localhost:8080/helloworld/home, it says requested resources not available. I can't figure out what's the problem. I tried out almost everything on internet for solution but nothing worked.

controller class:-

```
package com.helloworld;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller

public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String homepage(){
        System.out.println("hello world!!!");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hey Dude
</body>
</html>
```

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Hello-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 

<context:component-scan base-package="com.helloworld"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: What is context root of your project?

Comment: What is your project name?? tomcat context name?? is it really helloworld?? check in eclipse and post here...or go to manager.html and try to access from there

Comment: @VPK it's helloworld

Comment: check your browser console(right click and inspect element) you will find the error..it will be a link click on it,it will show the cause..share

Comment: @Sam there was no link in console.

Comment: try this link instead (omit the helloworld):  http://localhost:8080/home  if not ok try  http://localhost:8080/hello/home

Comment: @Sam for localhost:8080/manager.html it also gives resource not found error on browser

Comment: try this one: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm

Comment: @MarifQ it was my mistake it is `/html`....go to `localhost:8080/manager/html` and check for helloworld,click then add /home..and try

Comment: thanks @Sam but it gives same error. i think there is something wrong with my tomcat server.

Comment: @Sam ok i opened it from manager/html but it gives same error.

Comment: Ohh...see the tomcat console... While starting tomcat...is it giving any errors??

Comment: @Sam there is no error on tomcat console.

Comment: Atleast can u see something like `Oct 10, 2016 2:23:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/home/] onto handler 'helloworld'`...??

Comment: @MarifQ show your directory structure also

Comment: @Sam directory structure added.

Comment: @MarifQ can you see mapping url info on console?

Comment: @Sam No, there is no mapping url on console.

Comment: @MarifQ everything seems to be fine..but spring is not getting initialized or not scanning for controller..try the same thing using tomcat project and share the result...I mean Make a tomcat project ,copy paste classes,xmls,jars and run the tomcat and share the result